# The effect of removing many URLs from google search console

Tags: seo, google-search-console, nginx, laravel

I have been working as a web developer for several years, fixing issues, errors, and increasing page load speed etc. but I'm kinda new to SEO and Google Search Console.

I have a client who is using Laravel and due to his disorganized use of the routes and mistakes in link rewriting rules in Nginx config the website has ended up with thousands of wrong links indexed. I'm talking about 20,000 links.

So the client wants to redirect all those links to the correct content and keep them in the Google index so that the website ranking doesn't go down, but I don't think this is the best approach.

My question is whether removing this large amount of incorrect links will greatly affect to the website ranking/SEO negatively?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Fix External Links and Setup 301 Redirects

This is a 2 step approach for best effect.

1. Set all your old links as 301 redirects.
2. Find as many external links as you can that you can change them to the correct one. If you can't change them, try emailing the site or blog owner to have them change them.

Once you have done this, set all your 404's as fixed in Google Search Console.

Now everything should be fine and Google will love you.

*Keep an eye on the 404's console to make sure you didn't miss any!

Comment: nice, and since he is using laravel, return Redirect::to('/foo', 301);